# How can I create a randomly increasing matrix in r?

Tags: r, matrix, random

I wrote some codes as followings:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(fGarch)
T <- 11
N <- 200
a <- matrix(rsnorm(N, mean = 9.32, sd = 1.43, xi = -0.01), nrow = N, ncol = 1)
b <- matrix(0L, nrow = T, ncol = N)
b[1,] <- a
```

And now I want the matrix b to be a randomly increasing matrix by time(T). How can I get it in R?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `cbind()` or `rbind()` might be what you are looking for:

```
## Initial matrix
a<- matrix(1:9,3,3)
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# 1    4    7
# 2    5    8
# 3    6    9

for(i in 1:5){
  b<- i:(2+i)
  #Appending vector in rows
  a<-rbind(a,b)


}
a
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# 1    4    7
# 2    5    8
# 3    6    9
# b    1    2    3
# b    2    3    4
# b    3    4    5
# b    4    5    6
# b    5    6    7
```